# gestures and input stops after popviewcontrolleranimated or poptorootviewcontrolleranimated

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a main uinavigationcontroller that loads a uitableview as a subview as my "main view", I push a new uiview controller on, then in that viewcontroller I add a left nav button to popviewcontroller, bringing me back to the main view

all of that works just fine, the issue is when I pop back to the main view all input is doa, no swipes, scrolls, gestures, whatever, can't click on any of the table cells or scroll the table

not getting thrown to the debugger so I can only assume I haven't crashed the app, and I can do programmatic things in viewdidappear on the main view that affects the view, set timers, etc, but my screen input just doesn't work

any ideas as to where my input goes?

Comment: post some code, how do you pop, and push the controllers, and any other special coding that you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard without any code, but you're probably adding gesture recognizers to views in the view you just popped. You can try adding the gestures to UINavigationController's view, or window.view, or some other view that stays alive between navigation stack pushing/popping.

Comment: Spot on to the problem, or at least why I was seeing issues, I moved the gestures to the navigationcontroller.view and it works, what I don't understand is why ALL input stopped when I went back to the main view before, even the tableview's scrolling stopped.